# how to create a method put winecaseback

Tags: java

Hi guys i have created a browser class for my my project , i have created a method called select winecase which selects a winecase, however i am unsure how to

create a method putwinecaseback, which removes the wincase from the shopping basket by calling the method showBasket()

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Browser here.
 * 
* @author (johnson) 
 * @version (10/12/13)
 */

  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;


public class Browser
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int iD;
    private String email;
    private int yearOfBirth;
    private boolean memberID;
    private WineCase wineCase;
    private boolean loggedIn;
    private Website website;
    private boolean discount;
    private List<Boolean> baskets = new ArrayList<Boolean>();




 /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Browser
     */
    public Browser()
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = 00065;
        yearOfBirth = 1992;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

 /**
  * Constructor for objects of class Browser
  */
 public Browser(String newEmail,int newYearOfBirth)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = 0;
        email = newEmail;
        yearOfBirth = newYearOfBirth;
        loggedIn = false;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

 /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Browser
     */
    public Browser(int newID, String newEmail,int newYearOfBirth)
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        wineCase = null;
        website = null;
        iD = newID;
        email = newEmail;
        yearOfBirth = newYearOfBirth;
        memberID = true;
        discount = false;
    }

     /**
     * returns the ID
     */

    public int getId()
    {
    return iD;
    }


    /**
     * gets the email of the browser class
     */

    public String getEmail()
    {
    return email;
    }

    public boolean getDiscount()
    {
        return discount;
    }


    /**
     * gets the yearOfBirth for the browser class
     */

    public int yearOfBirth()
    {
    return yearOfBirth;
    }

    public double getWineCost()
    {
        return wineCase.getWineCost();
    }

      public double getWineCase()
    {
        return wineCase.getWineCost();
    }

     /**
     * returns 
     */

    public void setLoginStatus(boolean status)
    {
       loggedIn = status;
    }

    /**
     * returns 
     */

    public void selectWineCase(WineCase winecase)
    {
    wineCase = winecase;
    System.out.println ("Browser "+getId()+" has selcted wine case"+wineCase.getRefNo()+ "of "+winecase.getNoOfBottles()+ wineCase.getDescription()+ " at £"+wineCase.getWineCost()); 
    }

     /**
     * returns
     */

    public void payForWine()
    {
      website.checkout(this);  
    }

    public void setId()
    {
        iD = 999;
    }

     public void setWebSite(Website website)
    {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public void setDiscount(boolean discount)
    {
        this.discount = discount;
    }

     showBasket()

int counter = 8;
        int inc = 1;
        while ( counter <= 18 )
        {
            System.out.print ( " " + counter );
            if ( counter >= 14 && counter < 18 )
            {
                System.out.print ( " hello " );
            }
            counter = counter + inc;

            inc += 1;
        }

        public ArrayList<WineCase> getBasket(WineCase wineCase)
     {
        this.wineCase = wineCase;
        System.out.println ("Browser "+getId()+" has selcted wine case"+wineCase.getRefNo()+ "of "+wineCase.getNoOfBottles()+ wineCase.getDescription()+ " at £"+wineCase.getWineCost()); 
    }
}
```

any answers/replies would be greatly appreciated as i am confused.

Comment: I'm allergic to homeworks and I'm sneezing now.

Comment: winecase.? well are you kidding out here. And what is the question title: `how to create a method put winecaseback`

Comment: hmm.  Well, you need to give more information about what you've tried, what your errors are and what textbook, presumably, you're following.  Oracle has a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

For this question. Write your `putwineCase()` method like this:

```
public void putwineCase()
{
    /**
        Your logic here
    **/
}
```

This will work. Thankyou.